# How to update Foreign Key field of Profile model from webpage using django forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model called profile that has a field in it that links to another model called advertisement using ForeignKey. I am attempting to allow the profile that is signed in, to change the advertisement instance associated with their profile from a webpage using a submit button.

**This is the profile Model:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ethAddress = models.CharField(max_length=42, default='')
    advertisement = models.ForeignKey(Advertisement, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

---

**This is the form for changing the advertisement instance associated with their profile:**

```
class AdvertisementUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['advertisement']
```

---

**This is the View:**

```
def ad_update_view(request, my_id):

obj = Advertisement.objects.get(id=my_id)
profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)

if request.method == 'POST':
    ad_form = AdvertisementUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
    if ad_form.is_valid():
        ad_form.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Your account has been Updated!')
        return redirect('profile')
else:
    ad_form = AdvertisementUpdateForm(instance=profile)
context = {
    'ad_form':  ad_form,
    'object': obj,
}
return render(request, 'users/advertisement_update.html', context)
```

---

**This is the template that the user will use to change the advertisement associated with their profile.**

```
{% extends "website/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <article class="media content-section">
        <div class="media-body">
            <form method="POST">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                    <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ object.advertiser }}</a>
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                </div>
                <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.ad }}</h2>
                <p class="article-available">Money Available: ${{ object.available }}</p>
                <p class="article-ppc">PPC: ${{ object.ppc }}</p>
                <p class="article-thumbnail">{{object.thumbnail}}</p>

                    {% csrf_token %}
                 <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" name="get_URL">Use Ad</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </article>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing in your form, but if you want to update the current user profile, you can pass it as an instance to your form like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def ad_update_view(request, my_id):
   profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
   ad_form = AdvertisementUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
   ...
```

In your form you would only need the `advertisement` field:

```
class AdvertisementUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['advertisement']
```

Comment: I did this and it makes sense but it still doesn't take the advertisement that is displayed in the view and save it to the profile

Comment: @Benjamin I don't see any ```<input>``` in your form